# Hidden Footnotes in presentation

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I have a presentation where bullet points appear after each other. In one of those I am citing a work using \footnote. Unfortunately, the command does not care about the \pause command, meaning that the citation appears already on the first slide of the frame. Down below is a minimal working example. Ideally, I would like that the citation appears simultaneously with the second bullet point.

It would be great if someone could help me out. In particular, any command which does the job is more than welcome.

Cheers,
Max

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Unfortunately, the footnote appears already before the second point
        \item \pause ... where the actual citation takes place\footnote{Citation}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: `\only<2->{\footnote{Citation}}` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg! That is what I was looking for! Max

Comment: @egreg: Make this an answer. OP: Please accept egreg's answer if he makes one, otherwise accept Hunsu's.

Answer (score 7):

Like egreg said you should use \only<> command. In your example you should do

```
\only<2->{\footnote{Citation}}
```

That's mean that `\footnote{Citation}` will appear just after you next your presentation on that slide.