# Overlay specification in beamer with a pause

Tags: beamer, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

This is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178861/hidden-footnotes-in-presentation); however I am using pause, and not only. I would like to continue using pause.

I read through [this](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109wright.pdf), which is helpful. I think the issue is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118473/how-to-show-content-only-on-the-current-slide-in-a-beamer-specification/118475#118475) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-do-i-get-the-right-number-of-pauses-after-a-list-in-beamer).

My problem is that if I have a footnote after a pause using an overlay specification, the footnote turns up one slide too early.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  ignorenonframetext,
]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme[]{metropolis}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title of Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item List item 1 
\end{itemize}

\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item List item two
  \note[item]<2>{This is a note for the second item}
\end{itemize}

\pause

\begin{itemize}
\item Third item
  \note[item]<3>{Also with a note}
\end{itemize}

\pause

%\begin{block}{A Box}
\begin{itemize}
  \item This needs a reference\footnote<.->{Here is some other info.}
%\end{block}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is slide 3:
[image]

Here is slide 4:
[image]

As you can see, the value of `beamerpauses` is 4, so I am not sure why the footnote is showing up on slide 3.

If I change the overlay specification for the notes to a `<.>` they also appear one slide early. So the problem is the overlay specification with `pause`.

For completeness, the reason I am using the `<.->` specification overlay for the footnote is because I am using pandoc to go from markdown to beamer, and this is what is uses after a pause, which I think is correct. I would expect that the pause would increment, and then the `<.->` specification would use that value (assuming that `pause` is something similar to `<+->`). But it appears to be using one less. Perhaps this is where the relative offset (section 5 from the TUG article linked above) would be needed, but I cannot understand *why* it would be needed.

**EDIT**:

I just found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer) and then read section 9.6.4 in the beamer manual. So it appears that the `<.->` specification is not useful when using the `\pause` command, because it will always be off by 1. Is there a way to say "this current slide" without using the relative offset of `<.(1)>`?

Comment: Had a similar question, but your EDIT answered it. Thanks!!!